# how to get foursquare venue category from URL or specific venue id

Tags: categories, foursquare, checkin

I have some checkin data and I want to find the high-level hierarchy of each checkin location. However, I only have the location URL or very specific venue id such as `30bf7fef499adda0`. So is there any method to find foursquare category hierarchy based on these information?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the venue id you can call the [venue/details](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) api. The response includes a `categories` object with an array of categories associated with the venue. You can get the full category hierarchy at `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories`